# How to get the URL or ['u'] based on the user

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am developing a social networking site which, naturally, will have many registered users. I am trying to obtain the

For example, I have a page - profile_page.php which displays the profile page of the user. If a user manually types a users name in the browser, it would redirect them to the users page (if it exists).

I.e. at the moment when I go onto my own created profile, the url displays the following: `http://localhost/profile_page.php` what I want and need it to display is `http://localhost/profile_page.php?u=Freddy` or something similar.

What I have tried:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
    $user_u_var = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_GET['u']);
    if (ctype_alnum($user_u_var)) {
    //check if the user exists
    $check = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT username, first_name FROM users WHERE username='$user_u_var'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check)===1) {
        while ($get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check)){
        $user_u_var = $get['username'];
        $fname = $get['first_name'];    
        }
    }else { // refresh page 
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://localhost/www/index.php\">"; 
        exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I expected that writing the above code, would allow me to view the users name after the u= in the url, and allow me to search a users name and be directed to it, for example, if I search `http://localhost/profile_page.php?u=Jason` in the url, I would be directed to the page for Jason - but neither are working, the url still remains as `http://localhost/profile_page.php`

Comment: So you're saying that when you type `http://localhost/profile_page.php?u=Jason` into the address bar, you get redirected to `http://localhost/profile_page.php`?

Comment: @Patrick - When profile_page.php is loaded on a browser, the address bar says: `http://localhost/profile_page.php`. But I need it so that a user can type in `http://localhost/profile_page.php?u=Jason` for example, and be redirected to that users profile page, in this case, to Jason's profile page.

Comment: What is the behavior of the code that you posted in your question though? Your last sentence makes it sound like even if you pass the `u` parameter, you are being redirected to the page without it. Or is the parameter still there, you're just not seeing the expected data displayed? It's kind of unclear what is currently happening and what you want to happen.

Comment: @PatrickQ - Just a bit more background. The reason I need the u parameter is because I have an "Add Friend" button on my website. I need to store information on who the friend request is from, and who is it being sent to: `$request_sent_to = $user_u_var; 
     $request_sent_from = $username; // which is the session variable`. With the code stated above, when I manually type in `http://localhost/profile_page.php?u=Jason`, I will be directed to Jason's page. However, when I go back to the home page (of the logged in user), the url just says `http://localhost/profile_page.php`.

Comment: @PatrickQ .. I expect it to say the name of the user logged in, i.e. is Fred is logged in, it would say `http://localhost/profile_page.php?u=Jason`.

Comment: You should add more of your code to your question, and point out exactly what part of it isn't working, what the expected behavior is, and what the actual (unexpected) behavior is. As it stands now, you don't seem to be stating a clear problem.  You say you want information displayed, but the code above doesn't have any attempt to display anything.